# Un suported operand type(s)

Tags: python

```
home = os.getenv("HOME")
cokifile = home + "/.cookies"
```

and the error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Aaryan\Comple Python Cource\GUI chat application\ex.py", line 29, in 
> cokifile = home + "/.cookies"
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Can you check the output of the "home".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the home variable has value `None` and the operator `+` does not support `None`.
You need to validate the value of `home`, when you want to use it further. For example like below.

```
home = os.getenv("HOME")
if home is None:
    home = ""
cokifile = home + "/.cookies"
```

EDIT: I just found [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) has a second parameter `default`, so you can specify a default value to take if the env variable is not set:

```
home = os.getenv("HOME", default="")
cokifile = home + "/.cookies"
```

Comment: oh god ... you are a genius bro.. i search it from a hour and you just solve it ... thank u so so so much....

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be constructing the path yourself. As you have discovered, it is easy to make unfounded assumptions, and also the technique is platform-specific.

Do this instead:

```
os.path.expanduser("~/.cookies")
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you do not have any environment variable named 'HOME' when running your code. So, `os.getenv("HOME") will return None.

So, None and 'str' are not compatible when using the `+` operator.